# AWS glue job to map string to date and time format while converting from csv to parquet

Tags: pyspark, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

while converting from csv to parquet, using AWS glue ETL job following mapped fields in csv read as string to date and time type. 
[image]
this is the actual csv file 
[image]

after mapping and converting, date filed is empty and time is concatenated with today's date
[image]

How to convert with proper date and time format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses presto datatypes so data should be in correct format

> DATE Calendar date (year, month, day).
>
> Example: DATE '2001-08-22'
>
> TIME Time of day (hour, minute, second, millisecond) without a time
> zone. Values of this type are parsed and rendered in the session time
> zone.
>
> Example: TIME '01:02:03.456'
>
> TIMESTAMP Instant in time that includes the date and time of day
> without a time zone. Values of this type are parsed and rendered in
> the session time zone.
>
> Example: TIMESTAMP '2001-08-22 03:04:05.321'

You may use:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp, to_date, date_format

df = df.withColumn(col, to_timestamp(col, 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'))
df = df.withColumn(col, to_date(col, 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
df = df.withColumn(col, date_format(col, 'HH:mm:ss'))
```