# AWS Glue PySpark context modify date format

Tags: datetime, pyspark, timestamp, datetime-format, aws-glue

DateTime field will contain value like `Fri Mar 19 06:34:45 IST 2021` in String format.

This has to be converted to `dd:mm:yy hh` format. E.g. here the output would be `19:03:2021 06`.

Existing ApplyMapping is `("datetime", "string", "datetime", "string")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS glue job to map string to date and time format while converting from csv to parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176546/aws-glue-job-to-map-string-to-date-and-time-format-while-converting-from-csv-to)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Fri Mar 19 06:34:45 IST 2021', )], ['c1'])

trim_weekday = F.regexp_extract('c1', '\w+ (.*)', 1)
timestamp = F.to_timestamp(trim_weekday, 'MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy')
df = df.select(F.date_format(timestamp, 'dd:MM:yyyy HH').alias('date2'))

df.show()
#+-------------+
#|        date2|
#+-------------+
#|19:03:2021 06|
#+-------------+
```

I trimmed the 1st 4 characters using regex, because I couldn't succeed using `to_timestamp` with weekday.

Comment: Thankyou for reply. Its helping for one data (but HH is always coming with 2 number less.. 
Lets say 08:50:40 then HH will be 06 not 08.)
If same regex solution wanted to apply for entire column where multiple tables are concatenated, how can we achieve.

Comment: What if you try `trimmed = F.regexp_replace('c1', '\w+ (.*) \w+( \d+)', '$1$2')` and `timestamp = F.to_timestamp(trimmed, 'MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy')` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its now giving the exact hours.
I tried using the existing column in place of 'Fri Mar 19 06:34:45 IST 2021' but the result is NULL. This is the main requirement to extract the date from multiple rows in a column.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: This code is designed for only this format: `'Fri Mar 19 06:34:45 IST 2021'`. If you need code for other formats, you need to show them. Now you only showed this format. Please edit your question if it does not properly represent your problem. But if it is a different question, please post another question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue to apply for multiple rows in a column and the below code worked for me.

```
          maindf = maindf.withColumn('date2', when((length("Date")) >= 1,
        F.date_format(F.to_timestamp(F.regexp_replace(maindf["Date"], '\w+ (.*) \w+( \d+)', '$1$2'), 'MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy'), 'dd:MM:yyyy HH')))
     
          maindf.where(maindf['date2'].isNotNull()).select('date2', 'Date').show()
```